# How can I create GroupRadio from ArrayList<Integer> as listview in the xml file

Tags: android, xml, listview

I am getting arrayList [5,8,13,18,19] from the server and I would like to create a RadioGroup  in the xml file and not as AlertDialog. After selecting the diserable items, I will put the selected items in arrayList and transmit the query to the server after clicking the OK button. How can I create such as dynamic RadioGroup?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You don't dynamically create xml, you can dynamically modify views by referencing them via their resource id provided in xml. For this though, you just need to programmatically create a RadioGroup

Comment: @zgc7009: but how can I modify views by refercing xml content if I have the following method `createRadioButton()`?

Comment: Just look up how to dynamically create a RadioGroup and rework the logic to do what you need

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `ListView` (in xml or Java code) and fill it with elements from the ArrayList using `ListAdapter`.
Elements in `ListAdapter` should have layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice` and you should call `setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)` on `ListView`.

While OK button is pressed you can get selected item with `ListView.getSelectedItemPosition()`.